# How to rotate labels of WinRTXamlToolkit column chart?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I have the following `XAML` definition:

```
<Charting:Chart x:Name="ColumnChart"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Width="Auto"
                Height="Auto"
                Padding="50"
                Title="100 random numbers">
    <Charting:ColumnSeries Title="Skills"
                           IndependentValuePath="Name"
                           DependentValuePath="Pts"
                           IsSelectionEnabled="True">

    </Charting:ColumnSeries>
</Charting:Chart>
```

How can I rotate the labels (let's say on -90 degrees) in order to make them more readable?

[image]

Comment: Is there a template available for the label content?

Comment: The label content is basically in the following format `XX.XX - XX.XX` where `X` is a digit (it is a range). The ranges are calculated using some `C#` code.

Comment: Is there a property like ColumTemplate that would allow complete customization though? (I couldn't find any docs)

Comment: @WiredPrairie Same here, I have find a few years old example which was not working. There is no any up-to-date documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rotating the labels is possible. It requires a few steps, and unfortunately, due to a missing feature in WinRT XAML layout, a custom class potentially.

The core idea is found [here](http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9974032).

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Charting:Chart x:Name="ColumnChart"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Padding="50"
            Title="100 random numbers">
        <Charting:ColumnSeries Title="Skills" x:Name="theColumnSeries"
                       IndependentValuePath="Name"
                       DependentValuePath="Pts"
                       IsSelectionEnabled="True">
            <Charting:ColumnSeries.IndependentAxis>
                <Charting:CategoryAxis Orientation="X">
                    <Charting:CategoryAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="Charting:AxisLabel">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Charting:AxisLabel">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedContent}">
                                            <TextBlock.lay
                                            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="-60" />
                                            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Charting:CategoryAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                </Charting:CategoryAxis>
            </Charting:ColumnSeries.IndependentAxis>
        </Charting:ColumnSeries>
    </Charting:Chart>
</Grid>
```

The C# code I used:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rnd = new Random(444);
        ObservableCollection<Demo> values = new ObservableCollection<Demo>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            values.Add(new Demo() { Name = (rnd.NextDouble() * 100).ToString(), Pts = i });
        }


        ((ColumnSeries)ColumnChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource = values;
    }
}

class Demo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Pts { get; set; }
}
```

But, unfortunately, it's not exactly what you'll want. The problem is that there isn't a LayoutTransform like exists in WPF. If you run the code as is shown above, the labels are rotated, but they will overlap other content.

[image: Rotation not right]

The author of the blog has written a [LayoutTransformer](http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9455117) class that may help solve the problem, although it was designed for Silverlight (so it may be portable and work with WinRT XAML).

Comment: You could also use the [`LayoutTransformControl`](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/LayoutTransformControl/LayoutTransformControl.cs) from the toolkit to do layout transform on the labels.